# How can I change player skin in Cordova streaming media plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have created a small video streaming application in Ionic 3 using Cordova streaming media plugin.

It is working good, now I want to customize the skin of the streaming player and its buttons.

How to change skin of the player?

Is there any option to change or should I use media player plugin for customization?

I created video streaming app using this sample below:

- https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-media-streaming/

Comment: I guess you're using the video tag, right?

Comment: i want to customize Buffering Spinner in Cordova Streaming Media plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently offer skinning of the player. You're welcome to open an issue in the repo and see if someone will get it developed for you.

Comment: Sir, How can i stop  Video? is there any function to stop streaming? same as `stopAudio();`?